# TypeORM getRepository.find() does not include Foreign Key Fields

Tags: orm, typeorm, ts-node

I am trying to fetch all the columns included on my `entity`, but I only able to fetch the columns that does not have any relationship from the other entity.

I use this block of codes to fetch the all the rows to this repository.

```
private translationTextRepository = getRepository(TranslationText);

async all(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    return this.translationTextRepository.find();
}
```

And here's the `entity` for this repository.

```
@Entity('TranslationText')
export class TranslationText {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    ID: number;

    @Column()
    CreatedBy: string;

    @Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
    CreatedDate: Date;

    @Column()
    Status: boolean;

    @Column({ nullable: true, default: null })
    ModifiedBy: string;

    @Column({ type: 'timestamp', nullable: true, default: null })
    ModifiedDate: Date;

    @Column()
    Text: string;

    @ManyToOne((type) => Locale, (locale) => locale.ID)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'LocaleID' })
    LocaleID: Locale;

    @ManyToOne((type) => TranslationTitle, (translationTitle) => translationTitle.ID)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'TranslationTitleID' })
    TranslationTitleID: TranslationTitle;

}
```

But I was only able to fetch all the columns except the `LocaleID` and the `TranslationTitleID`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

Check this document:
https://typeorm.io/#/relations-faq/how-to-use-relation-id-without-joining-relation
solution:

1. define new column:

   @column()
   LocaleID: number

rename old one to : Locale

But typeOrm cannot sync your table due to foreign key problem.

2. use eager option in @ManyToOne({eager: true})

The search result will contain relation Locale object, you can take id from it.

Comment: In Dec 2020 I was about to get #1 working. The only modification that I had to make is to my seeding files for the non nullable ID columns. From `this.user = context?.user` to `this.userId = context?.user?.id`. Defining an id column is preferred to eager loading or defining relations. Getting FK only (vs all fields) improves performance. Also a full query may cause errors when you try to save a model with nested objects: the server might try to overwrite those nested objects in the DB. Defining the FK ids explicitly give you the most control.

Comment: Also, having the id column makes `find` a bit easier. Compare `let findOpt = {where:{user:{id:'asdf'}}` vs `let findOpt = {where: {userId: 'asdf'}}` ... `await ModelClass.find(findOpt)`

Answer (score 5):

Can you try to specify the relations like that:

```
async all(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
   return this.translationTextRepository.find({
     relations:["LocaleID","TranslationTitleID"]
    });
}
```

Because you have to make explicit that you want your relations on the query.